# Increment slice object?

Tags: python, slice

Is it possible to change the values in a python slice object?

For example, if I have

```
slice(0,1,None)
```

How would I, in effect, add 1 to the start and end values and so convert this to:

```
slice(1,2,None)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a complicated data format. At the moment it's being extracted a row at a time with a slice object identifying the row. The vendor's format is sometimes in a different orientation to the standard format i.e. 0 2 1 3 rather than 0 1 2 3. The easiest way in the code I have to get this in the right order would be just to add or subtract 1 to the relevant slices this switching rows 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly elegant, but it works:

```
>>> s1 = slice(0,1,None)
>>> s2 = slice(s1.start + 1, s1.stop + 1, s1.step)
>>> s2
slice(1, 2, None)
>>>
```